# Writing a program which organizes data entered into a matrix:

Tags: r

New to R and programming. The following is the code I have so far.

```
user_input <- readline(prompt = "Enter the data: ");
input_split <- strsplit(user_input, ",")
rows1<- length(input_split) / 2
finalmatrix <- matrix(c(input_split), nrow = (rows1), ncol = (rows1))
print(finalmatrix)
```

Could someone tell me why this is not working? Thank you for your help.

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do? “Organize data” is a bit too broad. Can you explicitly state what you want to do, your expected output, and provide example data?

Comment: Ah, I just wanted an input of strings/integers or any data from the user to be put into a matrix. I see that my code is logically incorrect, especially with the rows1 variable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: use **ceiling(length(input_split) / 2)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the list(), when we use the strsplit, the output will be a list, however we need to convert it into a vector and then use

### code

```r
user_input <- readline(prompt = "Enter the data: ");
input_split <- unlist(strsplit(user_input, ","))
rows1<- length(input_split) / 2
finalmatrix <- matrix(c(input_split), nrow = (rows1), ncol = (rows1))
print(finalmatrix)
```